# Allow users to format SSRs report

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2008, report, datasource

Is it possible to allow a group of users to format SSRS report (ordering columns, column width, eliminating wrapping, etc.), but not let them see/edit the dataset?  Let me know if I need to setup my report/data source/dataset certain way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to let them design the report in Report Builder with just a sample of dummy data. This would be ideal if you were only planning on having this done once initially.

If you want them to be able to manage the template on an ongoing basis, you could give them access to a table that stores the settings. You can include that table as a Dataset in your report. You can set expressions for properties like this:

```
=First(Fields!FontColor.Value, "Format_DataSet")
```

Most of the formatting for SSRS reports can be dynamic based on expressions like this.